# How Can I extract data of employee using a data in image attached

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5VqX.png)

I'm a begginner in google sheet don't now much but need to make an attendance sheet where I can get first Name of employee and employee Id and their punch time (In Time & Out Time). I've attached a link of google sheet for better understanding
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ai1cf3M6WPPkz-YTwoQqSe6hd6542AZV1HupSlpqtBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. I can't help you when I don't see column letters and row numbers :-) . It would be also very useful if you shared a copy of your sheet without sensitive data (you can change names for example). Is it "punch time" the same as "in Time" mentioned in your sheet?

Comment: Hi  Krzysztof Dołęgowski,I'm attaching link of g-sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ai1cf3M6WPPkz-YTwoQqSe6hd6542AZV1HupSlpqtBQ/edit?usp=sharing
and yes punch time is the same as in time also I need out time below that

Comment: Welcome! I have some problems understanding your set up. From where do you want to extract that data? This action could easily be done with Apps Script, would that be a valid solution for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jacques but don't know of Apps Script

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation in the comments I understand that you want to extract data from a Sheet cell, and you are willing to do so with Apps Script. To do so you only have to follow this [reading data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data) guide. Before developing that, please pay attention on how to create an [Apps Script embedded in a Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started).